# Child theme does not override parent theme values (custom-header)

Tags: custom-header

I have issues with putting my own default custom-header image for my child theme, but am unable to do so without altering the parent theme (twenty seventeen).

I'm able to remove the custom header with:

```
remove_theme_support('custom-header', 15);
```

But when I add them back in my child theme, the child theme still shows the twenty seventeen default custom-header image

```
$custom_header_args = array(
        'default-image'      => get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/images/header.jpg' ),
        'width'              => 2000,
        'height'             => 1200,
        'flex-height'        => true,
        'video'              => true,
    );
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $custom_header_args );
```

This is maybe best demonstrated with the minor modifications in the twenty seventeen /inc/custom-header.php file.

```
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-image'      => get_parent_theme_file_uri( '/assets/images/header.jpg' ),
        'width'              => 2000,
        'height'             => 1200,
        'flex-height'        => true,
        'video'              => true,
        'wp-head-callback'   => 'twentyseventeen_header_style',
    ) ) );
    remove_theme_support('custom-header');
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-image'      => get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/images/header.jpg' ),
        'width'              => 2000,
        'height'             => 1200,
        'flex-height'        => true,
        'video'              => true,
        'wp-head-callback'   => 'twentyseventeen_header_style',
    ) ) );
```

If I have it like this, the parent theme's header.jpg is shown as the custom header. However, if I comment out the first default-image definition, I see the child theme header.jpg.

So why are the previous values not overwritten? How are they even supposed to be overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do the `remove_theme_support`, just put yours in your `functions.php` file, make sure its a different image (might sound obvious but just in case):

```
$custom_header_args = array(
    'default-image' => get_theme_file_uri( '/assets/images/header.jpg' ),
    'width' => 2000,
    'height' => 1200,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'video' => true,
);
add_theme_support('custom-header', $custom_header_args);
```

the `child theme` custom header `theme_support` values will always override the values of the parent, its commented in the [core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L2298):

```
// Merge in data from previous add_theme_support() calls.
// The first value registered wins. (A child theme is set up first.)
if ( isset( $_wp_theme_features['custom-header'] ) )
    $args[0] = wp_parse_args( $_wp_theme_features['custom-header'][0], $args[0] );
```

the `functions.php` of the child theme will run first (registering the theme support first) then the `functions.php` of the parent.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I thought that I had tried this in the beginning but apparently I had something wrong there also :P